# Printing stderr to Screen without using stdout before redirecting it to a file in C

Tags: c, unix, fork, stdout, stderr

Is there any possible way to print out stderr on the screen without using stdout/printf before proceeding to redirect it to a file?

```
int pid = fork()  
if(pid == 0)  
    {  
      // file open  
      //dup2(file,2)  
      // print to screen how to?  
      // printf(stderr, "...")redirect it to a file  

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear and is possibly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Describe what you are trying to achieve rather than how you think it should be done.

Comment: If you want to print to both the screen and also save in a file, use the `tee` program.

Comment: I want to print a line on the screen and aswell as redirect it to a file by replacing stdout with stderr in child process. So basically print "Hi am rookie" on the screen and put this statement in the file. hope i made it a bit clearer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are still confused, reread @Barmar's comment. You use the `tee` program in your shell to accomplish this as you run your program. (obviously within your program you would need to write to both `stdout` and `stderr` in two separate calls or write a function that does that)

Comment: how do i implement "tee" in C. Can't figure out a way to do it.

Comment: the `tee` utility is used on the command line, similar to: `myprogram myparameters &2> tee myoutFile